# Looking for a good chess program with a couple of features

Tags: software

I'm looking for a good chess program with the following features. The game should

1. Randomly select whether I take white/black
2. Allow me to have a handicap against the computer
3. Have different difficulty levels

Any suggestions?

Comment: (2) and (3) are very common, but I'm not aware of (1). If you are okay without (1), I'm sure you'll have many possibilities.

Comment: Ok..What are your suggestions provided i don't want (1)?

Comment: Throw a die, with 1-3 you start a new game as white, with 4-6 as black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubisoft's *Chessmaster:  Grandmaster* Edition fits the bill:

1) Randomisation

This is available as an option in ranked play:

[image]

2) Handicaps

Are dealt with in the setup position mode (but unfortunately there isn't a randomised colour option in this part of the software. I would suggest rolling a dice)

[image]

3) Difficulty levels

Elo ranges from 0 to 2928 with a range of personalities (attackers, defenders etc.)

[image]